# Mat-toolbar won't take primary colour

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav

Following the very simple steps to create a responsive toolbar with sidenav, I have a small issue that's been driving me crazy.

From the basic schematic of `ng generate @angular/material:navigation sideNav`

[I want the toolbar to seem to extend over the sidebar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l99IS.png)  There's already a toolbar there but in the default schematic it's css is set to inherit the background:

```
.sidenav .mat-toolbar {
  background: inherit;
}
```

So if I comment that out and then add the colour to the `<mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>`

[I get this white line separating the two toolbars.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0xva.png)

I could manually make a toolbar outside of the sidenav div but I'm pretty sure that's the wrong way to go about it and I feel like there's something really simple and obvious I'm not getting.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please check this link https://stackblitz.com/angular/aydlejkdgvn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html? This is what you expeccted? @user2793505

Comment: It is not problem of mat-toolbar but of side-nav, class sidenav-container which has White bg is little bigger than side nav so you are getting that line.. you can set container color to primary if you want

Comment: @Muthupriya Yes, that's putting the toolbar outside of the sidenav. It works but I've heard that the sidenav should wrap the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement `fixedTopGap` from the [MatSidenav API](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api) - this will allow your sidenav to slide out under your toolbar with no overlap